# Suppose that f : [a, b] → R is continuous and that f([a, b]) ⊂ [a, b]. Prove that there exists a point c ∈ [a, b] satisfying f(c) = c.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

Suppose that $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f([a, b]) \subset [a, b]$. Prove that
there exists a point $c \in [a, b]$ satisfying $f(c) = c$.

(If either $f(a) = a$ or $f(b) = b$
there is nothing left to show, so you might as well assume that $f(a) = a$ and
$f(b) = b$. Since $f$ takes its values in $[a, b]$ this is the same as assuming that
$f(a) > a$ and $f(b) < b$.)

So far, I have:

Pf. Assume $f(a)>a$ and $f(b)< b$. 
Let $x, y \in [a,b]$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$ which means $f[a,b]=[x,y]$. Notice $[x,y]\subset [a, b]$. Since f is continuous on $[x,y]$, there exists some $c \in [a,b]$ such that $x$ is less than or equal to $c$ is less than or equal to $y$...

This is where I am stuck because I don't think I can just assume by Intermediate Value Theorem that some $f(c)=c$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Consider the difference $g(x)=x-f(x)$ on $[a,b]$. By your assumption, $g(a)<0$ and $g(b)>0$. Then you can apply the IVT to $g$ to conclude that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $g(c)=0$. At $c$, $f(c)=c$.